# Laravel can't make changes

Tags: laravel-5

When I'm working in my Laravel project it won't change anymore. I've already 
restarted wamp and updated with php laravel, but it keeps loading my stuff from a couple of days ago?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it may be cached. clear your browser cache and try ...

Comment: More information needed

Comment: Already tried in another browser. And the cache is cleared. It's very strange because for example I change a title of a page, but it doesn't when I load the page.

Comment: @jamie Where do you change the title?

Comment: @lukasgeiter in one of my views

Comment: @jamie try clearing the cached views with `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @Jon c  Thanks that worked!

Comment: @jamie have added it as an answer so we can get the question resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload`

It regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project.

This sort of problem caught me out early on when I added classes into my laravel applications.